# Why the UI elements disappear in seconds in Xcode 11.3?

Tags: ios, swift

I am coding a single view page IOS app in swift for learning in Xcode 11.3 on macOS Catalina. There are a button, a text field and a label elements on the page. Here is the code of `ViewController.swift`:

```
import UIKit
import LiquidCore


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var txt = "text field"
    @IBOutlet weak var Text: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func showText() {
        Text.text = txt
    }

    @IBAction func clickButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let url = LCMicroService.bundle("example")
        let service = LCMicroService(url: url)
        service?.start()

        txt = "LC started"
        showText()
    }

}
```

Here is the preview of the UI page:

[image]

The problem I am having is that all 3 UI elements disappear automatically in about 5 seconds after being shown on launch screen. There are view life cycles for a page but I don't have any of those in my code. What's wrong here?

Comment: what do you mean by disappear? from where? Can you show the storyboard design?

Comment: 3 UI elements disappear after loading. Just disappeared and left a blank white page with nothing.

Comment: You design exactly not on LaunchScreen?

Comment: All 3 UI element appeared on the launch screen as designed, but only stayed for about 5 seconds before all disappeared.

Comment: Hmm are you sure it's not an issue with the simulator? I've had some weird stuff malfunction on the simulator and usually restarting it / cleaning the project / debugging the simulator with work! Are you able to show us a video of the issue?

Comment: Checkout the HIG for the launch storyboard [https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/launch-screen/].  It specifically tells you that 'A launch screen appears instantly when your app starts up and is quickly replaced with the app's first screen, giving the impression that your app is fast and responsive.'.  So if you have designed those controls on the launch storyboard they will quickly be replaced.  Instead design a proper launch storyboard and then put all those controls on your initial storyboard proper

Comment: Found a Main.storyboard under my project. The file may be introduced by module LiquidCore installation (upon finishing the LiquidCore installation, it pops up saying the project should be opened with project_name.xcworkspace ). This main.storyboard is empty as it is. After deleting the Main.storyboard, the launch page stays with all 3 elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. This is basic of swift, I hope you designed it on `LaunchScreen.storyboard` which acts as the Splash screen of the application.
2. Your problem is you designed your view in `LaunchScreen.storyboard` so it stayed only for 5 seconds, now the solution is design your view in `Main.storyboard` so that you will see your `UIControls` or `UIElements`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: :) that's a really good point.

Answer (score 0):

> Copy paste all the designs from `LaunchScreen.storyboard` to
>   `Main.storyboard` and you will see the magic.

[image]