# With Version 12.2 beta 4 when I create a simple label in a new app it is not visible after a few seconds

Tags: xcode

I have the latest iOS and Version 12.2 beta 4. I had to upgrade from 12.1 because of having Xcode 14.2. I created a simple project in Swift and Storyboards. I dragged a label to the storyboard. I launched the project - It runs and shows the label for a second and then the screen goes black.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I was designing in LaunchScreen.storyboard not Main.storyboard.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60310278/211457